# Changing IntermediateOutputPath breaks C# compilation (MSB3491)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, configuration

I'm attempting to consolidate the intermediate outputs of building a Visual Studio 2015 solution to a single directory within my output directory. The solution contains a C# class library (among other projects).

In order to do this, the library project imports "common.proj", which defines the following:

```
<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(OutputPath)OBJ\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
<IntermediateOutputPath>$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)$(MSBuildProjectName)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
```

Prior to defining these values, the project compiled successfully. For the sake of clarity, $(OutputPath) is also defined in common.proj, and seems to be fine (i.e. when the build succeeds, it contains the expected outputs).

After defining the values, compilation fails with the message:

```
error MSB3491: 
Could not write lines to file "obj\x86\Release\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B1)BC5D3.cs". 
Could not find part of the path 'C:\Data\Repositories\Code\[Subsystem]\[subgroup]\[projectname]\src\obj\x86\Release\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B1-BC5D3.cs'.
```

I understand why the build process can't write to the file - the obj directory no longer resides under the project's src directory, so that's fair enough. What I don't understand is why it's trying to write to the file in that location, given I have changed base and intermediate output file locations.

I've missed something, but my googling hasn't pulled up anything particularly useful - any suggestions would be good.

Comment: OK, I'm going to follow this up with a *head-desk* - I deleted my top level directory, fetched from git and the error went away. However those temporary files are being generated in the [projectname]\obj\... directory, so the question still stands - why is visual studio writing intermediate output files to a directory other than the one specified by the IntermediateOutputPath variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While attempting to create a simple demo, I finally figured it out – my include project (Common.proj) was included before the import of Microsoft.CSharp.targets, however there was an additional import of Microsoft.CSharp.targets earlier in the file.

It looked similar to the following:

myproject.csproj:

```
<?xml version=”1.0”…>
<Project … >
    …
    <Import Project=”$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets” />
    …
    <Import Project=”$(SolutionDir)Common.proj” />
    <Import Project=”$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets” />
    …
</Project>
```

Once I updated it to reference Common.proj first and removed the second reference to Microsoft.CSharp.targets, it started building correctly.

Final myproject.csproj:

```
<?xml version=”1.0”…>
<Project … >
    …
    <Import Project=”$(SolutionDir)Common.proj” />
    <Import Project=”$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets” />
    …
</Project>
```